# Customize jFileChooser vertical scrollbar

Tags: java, swing

I'm using a jFileChooser and I'm trying to achieve the following :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/O6MNj.png

I'm trying to force the the **LIST** view to have a **VERTICAL** scroll bar or my second option is to disable the **size** and **modified** columns from the details view.

EDIT:

Is there any way that I can insert a JScrollBar inside the jFileChooser?

Comment: Please show your code

Comment: I have no code to show
I'm just creating a new jFileChooser object and I don't know how to achieve what I just asked.
Is there any way to access the scrollbar of the jFileChooser?

Comment: More choices [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/4446/6692).

Comment: Yes, I checked the documentation and I wasn't able to find anything helpful?

Is there any way to access the position of the scrollbar? or to disable the size & modified fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the JList and change the orientation of the list as follows:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;
import java.util.List;

class FileChooserList
{
    private static void createAndShowUI()
    {
        JFileChooser  fileChooser = new JFileChooser(".");

        //  Change list orientation

        JList list = SwingUtils.getDescendantsOfType(JList.class, fileChooser).get(0);
        list.setLayoutOrientation( JList.VERTICAL );

        fileChooser.showOpenDialog(null);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                createAndShowUI();
            }
        });
    }

}
```

The above code requires the [Swing Utils](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/13/swing-utils/) class.

> disable the size and modified columns from the details view

Depends on what you mean by "disable".

You can remove those columns from the view of the table:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;
import java.util.List;

class FileChooserDetails
{
    private static void createAndShowUI()
    {
        JFileChooser  fileChooser = new JFileChooser(".");

        //  Show the Details view of the file chooser

        Action details = fileChooser.getActionMap().get("viewTypeDetails");
        details.actionPerformed(null);

        //  Remove columns from view

        JTable table = SwingUtils.getDescendantsOfType(JTable.class, fileChooser).get(0);
        TableColumnModel tcm = table.getColumnModel();
        tcm.removeColumn( tcm.getColumn(3) );
        tcm.removeColumn( tcm.getColumn(1) );

        fileChooser.showOpenDialog(null);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                createAndShowUI();
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you very much!
The first solution was exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: Is there any way I can use getDescendantsOfType to get all the buttons like the list, details view and disable them?

Comment: Yes. The method returns a `List` of objects you are searching for., so you just iterate through the list. The above code knows there is only 1 JList or JTable, so is just accesses that component directly from the List.

Comment: I tried something like this
`JButton button = SwingUtils.getDescendantsOfType(JButton.class, chooseFile).get(button-index);
button.setVisible(false);`
I'm trying to disable all of the jFileChooser upper buttons, including the Look In field, but it didn't work

Comment: I don't know what "didn't word" means. Did it compile? Did you add any debug code to verify you found all the buttons? Your original question has been answered. If you have a problem with new functionality, then ask a new question with a proper [mre] demonstrating what you tried. I can't guess what you tried, and I can't post code in a comment.  Again, the suggestion was to 1) first get a `List` of buttons and then 2) iterate through the list. When I follow these two steps it works fine for me.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I have asked a new question.