# JFileChooser - adjust columns width

Tags: java, swing, jfilechooser, column-width

I've JFileChooser:

```
public static JFileChooser bakFileChooser() {
    JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
    fileChooser.setDialogTitle("Vyber BAK soubor");
    if (dataSource.equalsIgnoreCase(localdbInstanceName)) {
        fileChooser.setCurrentDirectory(new File(localdbDataPath));
    }
    else {
        Connection connection = connectionMap.get(dataSource);
        File backupDir = SqlServerBackupManager.getSqlServerBackupDir(connection);
        fileChooser.setCurrentDirectory(backupDir);
    }
    fileChooser.getActionMap().get("viewTypeDetails").actionPerformed(null);
    fileChooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_AND_DIRECTORIES);
    fileChooser.addChoosableFileFilter(new FileNameExtensionFilter("*.bak", "bak"));
    fileChooser.setAcceptAllFileFilterUsed(true);
    fileChooser.setPreferredSize(preferredDimension);    
    return fileChooser;
}
```

[image]

It works fine. The only ugly think is too low column width after directory is opened (or changed). User has to manualy adjust first column width to see full file/dir names.

How can I adjust the column width automaticaly after directory is opened / changed?

Or how to set fixed column width?

Comment: Check out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74070636/131872 for an example that shows how to access the JTable used by the file chooser. Once you have access to the JTable you can access the TableColumns and set your desired width.