How to retrieve pop up menu in JFileChooser toolbar
How to access jpopup that appears as a result of clicking the View Menu button. I need it for customize UI of that one.
I tried to access the jpopup object using an ActionListener, but it did not work.


Not exactly sure what you are asking about customizing the UI. Maybe this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74070636/131872 will give you some ideas.

Can you post an image of how you want it to look?

@Abra, for example change font, background and foreground according to the task. Unfortunately I don't have image

@camickr, I tried that, but the popupmenu object is created in a class WindowsFileChooserUI that is not accessible

There probably are ways to locate that menu, but they would not be stable.  Any later release of Java is free to change the internals of a JFileChooser.  For that matter, a future release of Windows might have entirely different file choosers, and eventually Swing will emulate those.  And, of course, your code would only work in Windows.  I would create a panel with your extra controls and pass it as the JFileChooser’s accessory instead.

@VGR, In that case, I'll probably remove the listener from the button that triggers the current popup and implement the call for a custom popup.

Maybe you can simply modify the look-and-feel.
